# Why this type of Data is used?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I have a very basic question on Java.

I understand data types like `int`, `String`, `float` and `double`; here is an `Array`:

```
Student[] s = new Student[100]
```

I understand that `s` is of type `Student`, but how and why do we need to make data type like this, if you anyone could explain with an example it would be more understandable to me.

Comment: You must read up some stuffs about Object orientation concepts

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
Student[] s
```

just indicates that s will be an array of students.

```
new Student[100]
```

will call the constructor, and (by the looks of things) actually return an array of 100 Students that you can perform actions on.

Without seeing the code for the `Student` class, I can unfortunately not be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will create an array that can hold 100 `Student` objects in the positions 0-99 (array indexes are 0 based). To add a `Student` to the first position, you would write something like `s[0] = new Student();`. `Student` isn't a pre-defined Java class, so you would need to define a Student class your self before creating it.

Answer (score 0):

This is related [Object-Oriented (OO) programming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/), in this case we have an object, Student.  We can define 1 of this type of objects like so:

```
Student studentObject = new Student();
```

If we wanted more than one of this type of object, how do we define it?

Just like how if we wanted more than one integer, or String objects, we can use a similar idea.  In this case they are using an [Array data structure.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Arrays/arrays.html)  Just like you would do

```
int[] integerObject = new int[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by your question, so I'll give a general answer. Before I do though, consider looking online for some basic tutorials to cover it, you should come to this place after you've tried searching.

**Student[] s = new Student[100];**

**Student[]**: this denotes that every object in this array will be type Student. Java is a strongly typed language, meaning it requires a clear definition of what something is-- e.g. you wouldn't have an array [1, "bug", true] because it does not have a clear type. Is it a array of Strings? ints? it's unknown.

**s**: simply the name of the variable. reference it as an array type.

**new Student[100]**: This is the constructor for the array type. The **100** denotes how large the array is, and therefore how many elements (in this case, **Student** objects) it can contain.

To make your data type **Student** is completely dependent on your code, probably something like `Student someStudent = new Student(<arguments needed in constructor>);`, and then you could add that to your student array **s** like `s[0] = someStudent;` Now, when you call the **s** array at its 0 index, you would get back the Student object you created (someStudent)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know what Array is.. Its a collection of Objects. if you want to store some integers, we use array of int - int[]. if we want to store some strings, we use array of Strings - String[]. Like wise if we want to store some students, then we use array of students - Student[].

Now coming to: Why and where do we need array of students.
Example - You are writing an application for a school and there are 5 class rooms. You want to list out the students of a class. Each student has say 3 properties - Name, ID, class.

First we create a template for a student (Student class)

```
Class Student{
      private String name;
      private int class;
      private int id; 
}
```

Then you create an array of students of a class. 
say if there are 50 students, then you will have only 1 array of 50 student objects.

```
Student[] class5Students = new Student[50];
```

Hope my answer helps you